# ReadProjectList from microsoft project server 2010

Tags: wcf, web-services, sharepoint

I wanted to read the list of the project using PSI web service in .net. I don't know what is the wrong, I always get the "Unhandled Communication Fault occurred" exception while requesting the web method.

Can some one help me to fix it plz.

I am using VS 2010

1. Added using web references and used the below code, ( actual username and password is given)
    web ref url : servername/ProjectServerName/_vti_bin/PSI/project.asmx?wsdl

   svcProject.Project prj2 = new svcProject.Project();
    prj2.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testuser", "testpassword");
    svcProject.ProjectDataSet lst2 = prj2.ReadProjectList();
2. I Tried with WCF reference also with below code

   ProjectSoapClient.ProjectSoapClient prj = new ProjectSoapClient.ProjectSoapClient();
               prj.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("testuser", "testpassword", "SDP");
               prj.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
               ProjectDataSet lst = prj.ReadProjectList();

I always get "**Unhandled Communication Fault occurred**" error,

some once can help to make the changes in the Project Server 2010 for the user permissions or authentication changes

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a try catch of the soapexception?

```
    catch (SoapException ex)
    {

        PSLib.PSClientError error = new PSLib.PSClientError(ex);
        PSLib.PSErrorInfo[] errors = error.GetAllErrors();
        PSLib.PSErrorInfo thisError;
        for (int i = 0; i < errors.Length; i++)
        {
            thisError = errors[i];
        }
        string StrException = ex.ToString() + " \r\nInner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.ToString();

    }
```

Have you tried login.asmx service for authentication rather than doing impersonification

```
 //Creating a new service client object
   ProjectDerived projectSvc = new ProjectDerived();
   projectSvc.Url = projectServerUrl + "Project.asmx";
   projectSvc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
   projectSvc.CookieContainer = GetLogonCookie();
   projectSvc.EnforceWindowsAuth = isWindowsUser;


// Get a CookieContainer property from the derived LoginWindows object.
private static CookieContainer GetLogonCookie()
{
    // Create an instance of the loginWindows object.
    LoginWindowsDerived loginWindows = new LoginWindowsDerived();
    loginWindows.EnforceWindowsAuth = true;
    loginWindows.Url = projectServerUrl + "LoginWindows.asmx";
    loginWindows.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    loginWindows.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();


    if (!loginWindows.Login())
    {
        // Login failed; throw an exception.
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Login failed.");
    }
    return loginWindows.CookieContainer;
}
```